# Adding bookmarklet to wordpress post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, header, xss, bookmarklet

I'm trying to add a javascript bookmarklet link to a post on my WordPress site. However it isn't coming out in the post preview. When I check the link that WordPress adds to the post it has converted it to `javascript:void(0)`. This simple example reproduces the problem.

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Alert!');">Search Scholar</a>
```

There are a few other people who've had the same problem [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-bookmarklet-javascript-in-href-inside-ltagt-tag?replies=2), [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/bookmarklet-hrefjavascript-not-getting-published-in-post?replies=2), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278035/javascript-in-a-wordpress-post), and [here](http://gnarf.net/2012/04/09/github-pro-tip-hide-red-lines-in-a-diff/) but no-one seems to have found a solution beyond just giving their bookmarklet code for people to copy and paste and create their own bookmarklet.

The cause of this problem is that Chrome's XSS protection is stripping out the javascript from the link when submitting it via wp-admin.  One "solution" is to add the line `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");` to wp-blog-header.php in the root folder.  This is insecure as it switches off the XSS protection on your WordPress site but it does allow the bookmarklet code to be rendered when the page loads.

Are there any real solutions to this problem that don't involve switching off XSS protection? Is there a perhaps a plugin I can install to my WordPress to allow me to add `javascript:` links inside my posts?

Comment: I've never used WordPress, but my first instinct would be to search the code for "void(0)".

Comment: You sure that it's Chrome that is stripping it out and not Wordpress? Do you only see this behavior in Chrome?

Comment: Other browsers (IE8+, probably others) understand this header, though there is no spec saying what it should do that I can find.  Chrome might be the only one that strips javascript out of bookmarklets, but I would imagine they all do things like strip <script>'s from posted data when that header is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT 2** After even more research, this is actually caused by the browser's XSS detection as mentioned by the OP (as opposed to any WordPress-specific functionality). The problem only arises when you click the `Preview` button in WordPress, and only on that initial page load. Apparently WordPress sends along some of the HTML in the request headers, and that triggers the XSS functionality in the browser. If you load the preview, and then you refresh the page, the XSS issue goes away, and the `javascript:` link is displayed as it was saved. When viewing the actual site, after publishing the page, this XSS issue is never encountered present.

**EDIT** After some deeper research (working with [@gnarf](https://stackoverflow.com/u/91914)), it turns out the actual issue comes down to the way that WordPress handles `javascript:` links in its preview functionality. It would seem that WordPress has some custom Javascript that runs and converts all `javascript:` links to `javascript:void(0)` links (stripping out any custom code), but only if you're previewing the page. After publishing the page, the `javascript:` links are rendered out properly.

---

**Original Post** (describes how to stop WordPress from stripping out `javascript:` links when saving a post as a non-admin user, which is what I assumed the original problem might have been)

It looks like WordPress strips out the HTML in the `content_save_pre` filter. Specifically, it calls the `wp_kses_bad_protocol` method in `wp-includes\kses.php`:

```
/**
 * Sanitize string from bad protocols.
 *
 * This function removes all non-allowed protocols from the beginning of
 * $string. It ignores whitespace and the case of the letters, and it does
 * understand HTML entities. It does its work in a while loop, so it won't be
 * fooled by a string like "javascript:javascript:alert(57)".
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param string $string Content to filter bad protocols from
 * @param array $allowed_protocols Allowed protocols to keep
 * @return string Filtered content
 */
function wp_kses_bad_protocol($string, $allowed_protocols) {
    $string = wp_kses_no_null($string);
    $iterations = 0;

    do {
        $original_string = $string;
        $string = wp_kses_bad_protocol_once($string, $allowed_protocols);
    } while ( $original_string != $string && ++$iterations < 6 );

    if ( $original_string != $string )
        return '';

    return $string;
}
```

The `$allowed_protocols` parameter is retrieved via the `wp_allowed_protocols()` method, which applies the `kses_allowed_protocols` filter to the list of protocols.

With this information, you should be able to tie into the `kses_allowed_protocols` filter to add `javascript` as a valid one (note that this, of course, would open up security issues):

```
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', function ($protocols) {
   $protocols[] = 'javascript';
   return $protocols;
});
```

One way to enhance the security of this approach would be to add a check for specific users or specific roles (by default, it looks like this filter actually *isn't* run on administrative accounts, so you can use `javascript:` links to your heart's content as an admin) prior to allowing the `javascript` protocol.

Comment: Part of me kind of loves that the final solution is that there never really was a problem, only the "preview" showed it.  I hope this solves the problem for the OP as well...

Comment: Confirmed, solved. Loading a preview of a previously published page shows the `javascript:void(0)`. After refreshing the preview page, the code appears as expected. Glad we got to the bottom of that.

Answer (score 3):

The initial problem is of course due to this:

> JavaScript cannot be added to post content without a special WordPress
>   Plugin that removes the filters that prevent unwanted code within the
>   post content area for the protection of the user.

To avoid installing a plugin you can use the recommended method:

> The safe and recommended method of adding JavaScript to a WordPress
>   generated page and WordPress Theme or Plugin is by using
>   `wp_enqueue_script()`. This function includes the script if it hasn't
>   already been included, and safely handles dependencies.

Here are all the details for `wp_enqueue_script()`:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

You then need to create a custom JavaScript file which you include and register with the functions you need for your posts.

You can in that file make a function which for example takes your bookmarklet link as an argument and do a `document.write` (or attaches a node to as child to a known element) to the current location.

Then include the script and call the function in the post as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
bookmarklet(myLink);
//--></script>
```

you only need to link the script ones in the same post - if you use this script in every post it's probably better to link it in the header (`header.php` template file, between the meta tags and the style sheet link).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

or alternatively if the above doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/pathto/myscript.js"></script>
```

Also note that if the `src` attribute is stripped away you need to go to Users and Personal Options in dashboard to turn off the rich editor.

Source and more information on how to use JavaScript in WordPress globally and in posts:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript#Javascript_in_Posts

Comment: Thanks for the info, +1 though I feel this falls short of answering the question.  Are you aware of a plugin that could do this already in existence?  I'd prefer not to go hacking on my own theme just to be able to add a bookmarklet link to one of my wp posts.  Are you suggesting maybe something like `<a href="#" data-bookmarklet="alert('boo')">bookmarklet</a>` and some JS that is included to do `$("a[data-bookmarklet]").each(function() { this.href = 'javascript:' + $(this).data('bookmarklet'); });` inside the post body? Can you give us some better steps to create this plugin/work around this?

Comment: @gnarf I was actually looking for a plugin to do this before I answered and couldn't find any. I did find generic plugins to share the page/post but not any where you could customize with your own link/script. I was considering making a demo on my own WP-blog but I cannot make it today. I'll try to update my answer with an example and demo sometime tomorrow. That being said, not being able to do this (at least at post level, no plugin, no config approach) is also an answer if that's the case IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the commitment! An answer I can implement by following some steps is what I want to see for the bounty. I feel like you probably have the know-how to bring this home and be a "guide to adding a bookmarklet to a wp post" style answer (with or without a custom plugin) :)